# How append sum of instances within a django queryset to that queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django Queryset object that looks like this (it is a derived queryset, not a queryset for a Model):

```py
<QuerySet [{'A': 2, 'B':3, 'C':0 }, {'A': 1, 'B':2, 'C':1 }]>
```

How can I append a new instance containing sum of instances within the queryset to that queryset? That is, I need to make a new (or the same) queryset that looks like this:

```py
<QuerySet [{'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':0 }, {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':1 },
{'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':1 }]>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. But if you use [**`aggregate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) then you will be able to get the sum of `A`, `B`, `C` like this:

```
>> result = YourModel.objects.aggregate(A=Sum('A'), B=Sum('B'), C=Sum('C'))
>> print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How should I use your code if I do not know the exact structure of Querysets (but yet they have the same structure)? Querysets derive through a process and they do not always have 'A', 'B', and 'C' fields.