# How append a python dictionary to the end of a django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django Queryset object that looks like this (it is a derived queryset, not a queryset for a Model):

```py
<QuerySet [{'A': 2, 'B':3, 'C':0 }, {'A': 1, 'B':2, 'C':1 }]>
```

I also have a dictionary with a similar structure to the queryset that looks like this:

```py
{'A': 1, 'B':4, 'C':7 }
```

How can I append this dictionary to the end of the queryset? That is, I will have:

```py
<QuerySet [{'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':0 }, {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':1 },
{'A':1, 'B':4, 'C':7 }]>
```

Comment: Could you put  the code you used to derive the original queryset

Comment: You already asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809355/how-append-sum-of-instances-within-a-django-queryset-to-that-queryset

Comment: @ruddra I think they are different questions. The mentioned question is about **aggregating and appending a Queryset to another Queryset**, here I want to append **a dictionary to a Queryset object**.